# NPM Install personal node library

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have created a library (`country`) in gitlab which I want installed in another project. This library uses another library of mine (`dataloader`). When I run `npm i` in my project, it installs `country` but then creates another node_modules inside country with dataloader. I want the dataloader library in the main node_modules. I am not able to understand why the dataloader package does not get included in the project node_modules

Expected Behaviour on npm i inside project:

```
Example Project
|
+--node_modules
  |
  +--country
  +--dataLoader`
```

Country Library Package.json
[image: Country Package.JSON]
Example Project Package.json
[image: Example project Package.JSON]

Problem :
Once i use to npm install in my Example project then i get folder structure like

```
Observed Behaviour on npm i inside the project:

Example Project
|
+--node_modules
  |
  +--country
     |
     +--node_modules
       |
       +--dataLoader`
```

but when i try to use npm install git+http://xxxxxxxxx/countries.git#master folder structure create as which i want.

eg:

```
Example Project
|
+--node_modules
  |
  +--country
  +--dataLoader`
```

Comment: Is this structure cause problem or failure in practice `dataLoader` module?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Verdaccio my issue has been resolve.

What is verdaccio?

Verdaccio is a lightweight private npm proxy registry built in Node.js

we need to create private.
Using verdaccio with any node package manager client is quite straightforward.
You can use a custom registry either setting globally for all your projects

```
npm set registry http://localhost:4873
```

then add .npmrc in your private library and your Example project

.npmrc

```
registry http://localhost:4873
```

then instead of publishing your private library on npm you need to publish on verdaccio.

using following command

```
npm publish
```

then using an your `npm install` folder structure is create correct which i want

```
Example Project
|
+--node_modules
  |
  +--country
  +--dataLoader
```